# Disabling Controls in Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap css and js in my application. Accidentally I clicked on a disabled Dropdown list and found that it's opening the dropdown. I have made it `readonly` in the attribute of the `select` element:

```
<select id="xxx" name="xxx" class="input-medium" readonly>
```

I have also tried setting `readonly="true"`, but still the same.

However, textbox control works fine, if you don't use jQuery.datepicker.

Is there a special way of making a dropdown control readonly when we use bootstrap?

Comment: Finally I found out. There is nothing to do with twitter. It's simple HTML. readonly only makes the control look like readonly. But disabled make the control disabled.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

No, Bootstrap does not introduce special considerations for disabling a drop-down.

```
<select id="xxx" name="xxx" class="input-medium" disabled>
```

or

```
<select id="xxx" name="xxx" class="input-medium" disabled="disabled">
```

will work. I prefer to give attributes values (as in the second form; in XHTML, attributes must have a value), but the HTML spec says:

> The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true
>   value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value.

(from http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attribute)

The key differences between read-only and disabled:*

The Disabled attribute

- Values for disabled form elements are not passed to the processor
  method. The W3C calls this a successful element.(This works similar
  to form check boxes that are not checked.)
- Some browsers may override
  or provide default styling for disabled form elements. (Gray out or
  emboss text) Internet Explorer 5.5 is particularly nasty about this.
- Disabled form elements do not receive focus.
- Disabled form elements
  are skipped in tabbing navigation.

The Read Only Attribute

- Not all form elements have a readonly attribute. Most notable, the `<SELECT>`, `<OPTION>`, and `<BUTTON>` elements do not have readonly attributes (although thy both have disabled attributes)
- Browsers provide no default overridden visual feedback that the form element is read only
- Form elements with the readonly attribute set will get passed to the form processor.
- Read only form elements can receive the focus
- Read only form elements are included in tabbed navigation.

*-blatant plagiarism from http://kreotekdev.wordpress.com/2007/11/08/disabled-vs-readonly-form-fields/

Comment: Very important: Values for disabled form elements are not passed to the processor method. The W3C calls this a successful element.(This works similar to form check boxes that are not checked.) !

Comment: The differences between read only and disabled is very helpful.

Answer (score 12):

try

```
$('#xxx').attr('disabled', true);
```

Comment: he is asking it using bootstrap and not jquery

Comment: Additionally since jQuery 1.6 this would be prop() instead of attr().

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
<select id="xxx" name="xxx" class="input-medium" disabled>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember for jQuery 1.6+ you should use the `.prop()` function.

```
$("input").prop('disabled', true);

$("input").prop('disabled', false);
```

Answer (score 1):

also you can use "readonly"

```
<select id="xxx" name="xxx" class="input-medium" readonly>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="message_tag">
<optgroup>
<option>
....
....
</option>
</optgroup>
```

here i just removed bootstrap css for only "select" element. using following css code.

```
#message_tag_chzn{
display: none;
}

 #message_tag{
  display: inline !important;
}
```